# Twitter Bootstrap carousel does not slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried the same code which is on the TwitterBootstrap website but still it does not work.

On their website it slides nicely but in my code it just flips the images.

Edit: In some of the high resolution screens. Ex: iPad the carousel flickers, so add following css class to ur css file. hope this would help

```
.carousel .item {
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: It may be the same as code on their site but post your code here if you would like some help

Comment: What browser are you using? The slide effect is a CSS3 transition. If the browser doesn't support it (e.g., <= IE9), it will just switch immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem and found that I included only parts of the javascripts and was missing the following include:

```
twitter/bootstrap/transition.js
```

after including this the carousel works with animation as expected.